# MediaPlayer plays the music files only in debug mode ( Android )

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I have written an Android application ( in eclipse) that plays a music file as follows:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileName);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        //  mediaPlayer.stop();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception---", e.getMessage());
        }
```

When I run it, it does not play the file  ( and does not show any exception ), but when I switch to 'debug mode', and trace it line by line, it plays the file. I'm really confused. Would you please help me find out what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put a log before "mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileName)" and check if you are getting a valid fileName in release mode.

Comment: Dear potter, I checked it, and in both cases ( debug mode and release mode) the file name is exactly the same. But it does not play anything in release mode. What's strange, is that the log does not show any exception in release mode, but simply does not play the file. When I insert a break point at first line and trace it line by line ( with F6, in eclipse), it plays the file, after running the mediaPlayer.start(); Thank you.

Comment: Please note, my program uses andEngine. Does this problem related to it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and in my case it didn't like the player.PrepareAsync() command. It wasn't giving any errors in debugger except some miniscule info in the output window which wasn't of any help. Realizing that something was tripping the player I started to change a few things and changed the player.prepareAsync to player.Prepare() and thats all it took in Xamarin.